# How can I tell which version of Voodoo to install?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, voodoo

I want to install Voodoo lagfix on my phone, and I see that there are a number of kernels for Froyo on [the download site](http://dl.project-voodoo.org/stock+Voodoo/tarballs/):

```
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XWJS3.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XWJS5.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XWJS8.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XXJPM.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XXJPO.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XXJPU.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XXJPX.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M     
stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XXJPY.tar   19-Mar-2011 03:18   5.7M
```

However, none of these version seems to match my phone.  This is what's shown in `Settings -> About` (sorry that it's in Hebrew, but it should be in the same order as English phones):

[image: About]

Based on this, what version should I install?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the filenames reflects the codename for the kernel version.  The phone only shows the version number, making things difficult.

The good news is that you can use any 2.2 kernel with a 2.2 ROM (or 2.3 with 2.3, etc.).  I'd just use the newest (they're alphabetical, so [JS8](http://dl.project-voodoo.org/stock+Voodoo/tarballs/stock+Voodoo-Froyo-GT-I9000-XWJS8.tar) is the newest).  You can always experiment and see which one gives you the best performance, or hit up the XDA forums where people will certainly have discussed it.

Comment: So basically I don't really have to worry about which one I have now, because I'm going to replace it anyway?

Comment: @Nathan Exactly.